# Writing to a peripheral in Vivado and then outputting to a LED

Tags: client-server, verilog, fpga, vivado, redpitaya

I want to create a basic project in Vivado that takes a value that i input to a client, which is sent to a server I made (in C), and then the server writes that value to a peripheral in Vivado, and then that data in the peripheral is sent to an output pin that assigns to LED's, making the LED light up.

Basically I want to go from client-->server-->peripheral-->LED lights up

For example, in the client (a GUI) I want to give it a value such as 0011, which is received by the server. Then the server writes that value to the peripheral which will then make, in this case, LED0 & LED1 not light, but LED2 & LED3 will light.

I know how to make an AXI4 peripheral in Vivado, and the client-server (TCP/IP) has been made. My question is what code/design block I would need to then take the data written to the peripheral and assign it to the LED's?

Should I make the peripheral a Master or Slave? Overall confused how should i proceed from here. I am using a Red Pitaya (Xilinx Zynq 7010 SoC) connected by an Ethernet cable to my computer.

Also, I thought of running the program on the Red Pitaya by loading the bitstream on to it (using WinSCP) by running the command

```
cat FILE_NAME.bit > /dev/xdevcfg
```

in PuTTY (connected to the Pitaya by IP address), then running the server on the pitaya, and then sending the signal from the client for the server to receive. Is that the correct way of approaching it?

If my logic is off in anyway please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am somewhat thrown by your statements.

- First you say "I know how to make an AXI4 peripheral in Vivado"
- Next I read: "Should I make the peripheral a Master or Slave?"

Maybe I am wrong but to me it says you don't *really* know what you are doing.

Simplest is to:

1. Instance a zynq system.
2. Add the IP with the name "AXI GPIO". (Which, by the way, is an AXI slave.)
3. Run the auto connection.
4. Assign the right I/O pins to the GPIO port. (check your development system manual)
5. Build the system.

By the way you find the address of the peripheral in the address tab and it normally is 0x0080000000.

You wrote that you made a server (TCP/IP). "All" it has to do is write the received value to a register in the GPIO block. (Here I assume Xilinx has a document which describes how the GPIO block works and has example GPIO drivers.)

Comment: Thank you for you response. I just want to clarify that once I assign the i/o pins to the GPIO port and generate the bitstream, the next step is to run the bitstream on the board (using the command in original post), and then run the server on the board, and assuming that the server is correctly configured to write data to the GPIO address, use the client to send data to the server, which in turn writes data to GPIO? After doing that the LED's should light up? Or am I missing anything else, logic wise.

Comment: I have no experience with the Red Pitaya board. I always have to use a Xilinx programming cable to program any of my (four) different Xilinx' development kits. I have not yet heard of a development board programming itself. But that does not mean it is not possible. (Somebody asked about that a few weeks back, so it is no unheard of)

Comment: OK I go the LED's to light using the above steps. You do need to load the bitstream on to the board and then run the server. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Congratulations. There are many small steps and details involved which I could not all outline. I am impressed you got the system working with only the outline above. Well done!